# How do i capture a %20 from a url in a regex for an .htaccess?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url

i'm trying to grab a string like `product/bob` which works, but `product/my%20first%20product` does not.

Here's my regex:

```
^product/([A-Za-z_\-\s\%20]+)$
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This works for me, what are you capturing in your capture group? `my`, empty, or something else?

Comment: To answer precisely, it is necessary to specify where you are using this regular expression. `Alias`? `RewriteRule`? Somewhere else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have written as your regular expression contains a few things in the collection which may not do what you expect, depending on the regular expression engine being used. `\s`: this could match `\` or `s`, not space or tab. `\%20`: this could match `\` as well as `%`, `2` and `0`. Anyway, you want to match `%20` in order. This means that you should use a branch. And if you put the `-` at the start or end, you don't need to escape it.

```
^product/((?:[A-Za-z_ -]|%20)+)$
```

(The `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group which is more efficient than the capturing group `(...)`.)

However, I think it quite possible that whatever it is that you're using turns the `%20` into a space character, and so you may be able to just turn the `\s` into a space and get rid of the `\%20`:

```
^product/([A-Za-z _-]+)$
```

Also consider whether you should allow more characters - for myself, I would use `^product/(.*)$` or `^product/([^/]*)$` - and handle it further in your script or whatever it is. But it depends somewhat on what you're using it with, and as you haven't specified that, I can't help immediately.

Comment: `\s` *will* match space or tab (and other whitespace). And `\%` will simply resolve to `%` (or might trigger an error in a more restrictive regex engine), but at no point will a backslash be matched.

Comment: @Tim: it depends upon the regular expression engine. PCRE will have `\s` match space and tab in a collection, but not all do; for example Vim's regular expression engine (which is, I will admit, different in quite a number of ways) does *not* do magic in collections for other than `\-`. It was upon this that I based my statement. I know not what regular expression engine is used in whichever portion of the `.htaccess` file he is dealing with, and so while it is not terribly likely, it is perfectly valid as a *possibility*.

Answer (score 0):

try this~

```
^product/([A-Za-z_-]|%20)+$
```